# How do I set the background color for my Canvas screen in my turtle game?

Tags: python, background, tkinter-canvas, python-turtle

I want to set a bgcolor for my Turtle game, but I don't know how to do that with the tkinter Canvas.
My turtle Code is combined with tkinter.

```
from tkinter import*
from turtle import Canvas, RawTurtle, TurtleScreen

root = Tk()
root.title("Pong Game")
canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.config(width=1200, height=600)
canvas.pack()
screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
```

I want to set my Background color to black.
If you know how to do it, or want to see more of my code, please tell me.

If I try to set my background color to black, it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Please post the code you used to try to set the background to black.

Comment: ```root = Tk()
root.title("Pong Game")
root.config(bg="black")

canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.config(width=1200, height=600)
canvas.pack()

screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
screen.bgcolor("black")```

Comment: I've tried all three, but the result is always the same @Woodford

Comment: `screen.bgcolor("black")` works just fine for me

Comment: OK. I've just tried it with snippets of my code, and from the point at which I paste my code into the mainloop, screen.bgcolor ("black") no longer works. Here is the code I tried to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the updated code you posted you're creating the `RawTurtle` object with the `canvas` instead of `screen`:

```py
SchlägerL = RawTurtle(screen)  # pass screen instead of canvas
```